# Footer links missing when in responsive mode (Firefox & Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I keep running into issue with my footer when in responsive mode using the Firefox or Chrome developer tool. Everything works fine When the width is around 859px. I have playing with the display, flex-flow and nothing seems to work. How can I fix this issue? Be mindful that I'm not familiar with flexbox, so any advice or help will be greatly appreciated.

[Example on when it's bellow 859px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4v3g.png)
[Example on when it's above 859px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoeEe.png)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #23374D;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

/* Navigation */
nav {
    background-color: #0085FF;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

label.logo {
    color: rgba(227, 227, 227);
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

label.logo span {
    border-top: 3px solid rgba(227, 227, 227);
    width: 80%;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: rgba(227, 227, 227);
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 7px 13px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul li a.active, nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #85c3ff;
    transition: .5s;
    color: rgba(34, 34, 34);
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.checkbtn {
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    float: right;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#check {
    display: none;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    position: sticky;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #85c3ff;
    padding: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer p {
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.footer ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    color: #23374d;
}

.footer ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3 ease-out;
}


.container {
    padding: 15px;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <label class="logo span">Site Name</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.htm" class="active">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        test
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p> &copy; <script type="text/javascript">
                document.write(new Date().getFullYear());

            </script> Site Name</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Provided Code working fine as you can see in fiddle, check some other external css files you included in your project may be that will override some footer styles

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted doesn't seem to be showing the behavior you specified in Chrome. You can try removing the 'position: sticky' property to see if that helps. Also, when applying display 'flex' to the body, it's a good practice to specify a flex property for each of the child element of the body (you have only specified for container, not for nav or footer). The default value of property 'flex' is '0 1 auto', which means that elements will shrink beyond its basis ( basis is alias for default width/height, whatever is relevant along the main axis of flexbox), if enough space isn't available (this might be causing foorer to shrink). You can also try to change the z-index of the footer to see if the links aren't overlapped. This article well summarizes the properties of flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox